# Is there an alternative for file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I tried this but getting only one character from file `comments.txt`

I want random lines one by one .. `file_get_contents` disabled also urlencode

```
$f_contents = file_get_contents("comments.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$messages = $line;
$messages = urlencode($messages);
```

Comment: have you tried fopen/fread/fclose ?

Comment: Do you want to print all random lines or a single random word from the file ?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're treating `$f_contents` like an array where it is actually a string

Comment: Yea! i have tried fopen/fread/fclose its also not working!

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yes i want to print all random lines

Comment: then what to do @Phil

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it like ..

```
<?php
$arr = file('comments.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
shuffle($arr);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
 echo $v."<br>";
}
```

The above code prints random lines from your text file one by one.

Comment: @user3563010, I never post code without testing. Can you explain not working ?

Comment: opps sorry! i have did the mistake so it doesnt work! now its working thank you so uch ! but now i am having problem with this $send=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/$id/comments?message=$messages&method=post&access_token=$m')

Comment: Can you give the URL ?

Comment: @user3563010, Accept this answer if the random array problem was solved. THanks.